# How would I use a variable for KeyWait or GetKeyState?

Tags: autohotkey

(this is my first post on stack so I apologize for any formatting issues.)
((v1 autohotkey))

So right now i'm trying to have a KeyWait use a variable, because the hotkeys are rebindable in this program i'm making as a single set of hotkeys doesn't work for other people.

The rebinding feature works like this.

```
rebind: ;a button thats pressed via gui
input := GetKeyPress(keys) ; list of joystick keys to grab from
variables1through5 := %input%
msgbox, you pressed %input%
hotkey, %input%, hotkey1through5, on
```

As of now i've tried some methods such as using keywait like this
`KeyWait, %variable%`
or

```
GetKeyState, outputthingy, %variable%
if (outputthingy = "U"){
dothings
}
```

But nothing really seems to work, KeyWait no matter what I put does the code anyways and GetKeyState seems to not run the code no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey **v1** is a **deprecated** version.

In this deprecated version, there are some **deprecated commands which are not recommended for use in new scripts**. And the way you use for `GetKeyState` is one of them.

### GetKeyState()

1. To Check if a key is currently down or up.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey >=1.1.36 <2

if GetKeyState(variable, "P") {
    MsgBox % "The " variable " key is down."
} else {
    MsgBox % "The " variable " key is Up."
}
```

### KeyWait

1. Waiting for a key or mouse/joystick button to be **released**.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey >=1.1.36 <2

KeyWait % variable
```

2. Waiting for a key or mouse/joystick button to be **pressed down**.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey >=1.1.36 <2

KeyWait % variable, "D"
```

Learn more about [GetKeyState()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GetKeyState.htm#function) and [KeyWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/KeyWait.htm).